# Error while reading data from excel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written some code that reads data from excel and displays the data in a message box. I took that code from a website. When I run the same, I get a few errors in two particular lines

The lines where I encounter the errors are as follows

```
 for (int i = 1; i &lt;= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j &lt;= colCount; j++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                }
            }
```

The full code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelReader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/C.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i &lt;= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j &lt;= colCount; j++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Can someone kindly help me wit the correct solution for this code?

Comment: Which error do you get? Why do you have "&lt"; in place of "<"?

Comment: "&lt" value is "<" in web browser, I suppose.

You should click on copy source code button in the web page if possible, don't copy native content in html.

Comment: @Thinhbk: yes sure, but this should be C# !!!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
for (int i = 1; i &lt;= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j &lt;= colCount; j++)
    {
```

with

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
```